# How do I exit my git commit message? I'm NOT in the VIM, I used the " commit -m " command

Tags: git, bash, github, terminal

I was trying to commit a message and I accidentally made a typo:

```
'git commit -m 'Deleted old Basic Syntax chapter README'
```

Now i'm stuck in the terminal, and all it shows is:

```
> 
>
>
>
>asdfasdfad
>
>asd
>
```

How do I exit out of this, but still keep my commit message? I'm fine with having to re-commit, but I dont want to have to exit the terminal because I'm sitting on a few commits that I don't want to lose. (If i'll lose them at all?)

Comment: What do you mean by "still keep my commit message"?

Comment: I originally meant to keep the "Deleted old Basic Syntax chapter README", but that probably won't be possible. I can deal with having to recommit that one, but my real concern is just not losing the other commits that i'm sitting on.

Comment: Ah I see. If this answer worked for you, could you accept it? Others may run into the same problem.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It wouldn't let me accept it because i had 'x amount of minutes left'

Comment: No sweat, glad your problem is solved `:)`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You won't lose commits by closing the terminal.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will exit the prompt `>`

What happened was you opened up a string with the odd number of `'` characters.
Bash expects more input for your string, and allows you to enter it after the `>` prompt.

Try typing `'` and hit <kbd>return</kbd>, you will get the same thing. If you close the string by typing '`' again, you will be back to your normal bash prompt.

Comment: Ok, so I suppose I'll just exit the terminal then. However, since this has happened to me on more than one occasion, is there a true solution to getting out of where i'm at?

Comment: Control-C doesn't exit the terminal; it just aborts the current command. However, you can also just supply the closing single quote (that's what the shell is waiting for) because the string `'git commit -m'` (as a single word) will not be a valid command name, and you'll just get a "command not found" error.

Answer (score 2):

Windows = Ctrl + C

Mac = Ctrl + C (No command, CTRL)

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+c will exit the prompt >

and then:

`:wq`

which means write and quit

Answer (score 0):

I happen to face the same issue right now.

In my case, I was trying to add an exclaim sign (!) in the git commit comment, where it replaced the second quote sign (") and went into the. "dequote" terminal mode instead of regular.

It means I am in multiline comment mode and have to end by dequote, but it seems to be stuck.

Ctrl + C (both for PC and Mac) ends the process and comes out of the dequote mode.

Now, I had to recommit the added files.

And it worked!!! :P